# How do you make the tkinter's message box stop waiting for an input before continuing the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So basically I'm trying to make a program that closes the specific program when you run it.

If I open google chrome, it should close it and give a fake error message.

But when I get the first error message, and open the program again, the Python file won't shut the program down because it is waiting for the message box input. How can I ignore the message box's input?

```
import subprocess
import time
import psutil
import os
import random
import tkinter

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def checkProgram():
    if "chrome.exe" in (i.name() for i in psutil.process_iter()):
        return True
    
def killProgram():
    subprocess.call(f"TASKKILL /F /IM 'chrome.exe'", shell=True)
    errormessage = "error message"
    tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Test", message=errormessage)

while True:
    if checkProgram():
        killProgram()
```

Comment: In the `killProgram()`, you can also try to iterate over the process in `psutil.process_iter()` and can use `os.kill(process.id)` instead of subprocess. And also you can use `tk_instance = TK()`, and in the the same function you can use `tk_instance.destroy()`

Comment: what are `tk_instance = TK()` and `tk_instance.destroy()` supposed to do?

Comment: `TK()` - this will create and manage the widgets. Creates an instance of tkinter frame/window.

`destroy()` - this will destroy the widgets. it terminates the mainloop process and destroys all the widgets inside the window.

Comment: Implement a modeless dialog by creating a ```Toplevel``` window. And rework the busy loop so it calls ```mainloop()``` and does periodic tasks by calling the ```after()```.